# What account to use for creating app ID

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, app-id

I would like to allow users to post to their Facebook wall from within my unity app (available for ios and android). I understand I need to create a FB app ID.

My question is this: what account should I log myself in as to create this app ID in the developers portal of Facebook?

I have a personal Facebook account that has nothing to do with my unity app. Can I use that account to create the app ID. But if I do that, will the app ID be bound to my personal account? What if I close my personal account? Will the App ID be still active if I do that? Should I create a business account in fb instead to create the app ID? Why do you need to log in to create the app ID in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can add other FB users as administrators of the app. So if you close your FB account - those other users can still administer that app.